# Questions on wildcards in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, wildcard, sql-like

[Sample 'gov_form'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EJYe.png) [The correct query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/levP6.png) [The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI6w9.png)

I'm working on a question which asks me to select countries where the form of its government is not 'Constitutional Monarchy' or 'Republic'.

The answer given is WHERE **(gov_form = 'Constitutional Monarchy' OR **gov_form LIKE '%Republic%'**)**. I tried to switch them off as **(gov_form LIKE 'Constitutional Monarchy%' OR gov_form = 'Republic')** but this is wrong, and apparently the number of rows was different.

Im so confused because there are two other fields that contain 'Constitutional Monarchy(Emirate) 'and 'Constitutional Monarchy,Federation' so why can't I use the wildcard '%'???

Also there are couples of 'variations' of 'Republic' such as 'People'sRepublic', 'Socialist Republic', 'Federal Republic' in the table just like those of 'Constitutional Monarchy'!! But considering the question is asking to not include 'Republic', why should I use '%' to exempt all the 'variations' of 'Republic'???

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Thinking a bit outside the box, normalize your design. Have a second table holding government forms and a reference to that on your countries tables, then you can simply filter by its ids and not by parsing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me

> Countries that do not have gov_form of Constitutional Monarchy

(bullet point 1)

means

> countries where gov_form <> (not equal) 'Constitutional Monarchy'

and

> countries that do not have republic in their gov form

(bullet point 2)

means

> Countries where gov_form does not contain the text "republic"

This would be

`WHERE gov_form <> 'Constitutional Monarchy' AND gov_form NOT LIKE '%Republic%'`

the subquery is looking to turn that on its head because it uses a `NOT IN`, so in the subquery, we are basically saying

> Show me those where gov_frm IS EQUAL TO 'Constitutional Monarchy' and gov_form IS LIKE '%republic%'

which are the records we *don't* want to see, the outer query excludes these by using the `NOT IN`

The question is poorly written and laid out in my opinion and definitely open to interpretation. I have re-written this answer three times based on three different understanding of the question. Furthermore, I would say this would be better solved and easily more readable with a regular `JOIN`

The biggest challenge with any programming task is understanding in human language what is required. Once that is done, the rest is "easy"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i've uploaded three pics at the beginning of the question. There are a sample of gov_form, the correct query given, and the original question. Don't bother with the economic data tho. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again for this explanation!! I too feel the question is poorly written and thus can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: no problem - please mark as the answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

where gov_form NOT LIKE '%Constitutional Monarchy%' AND gov_form NOT LIKE '%Republic%'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the records where government type contains `Constitutional Monarchy` or `Republic` then you can use `NOT` as follows:

```
WHERE not (gov_form like '%Constitutional Monarchy%'
           OR gov_form LIKE '%Republic%')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. NOT is useful although I was told to use subquery. Have a look at the three pics uploaded at the beginning of the question. There are a sample of gov_form, the correct query given, and the original question. Economic data are not necessary to look at for my question. Thank you!